# Use python re.findall to split the line

Tags: python, match

I am trying to use re.findall to split one string:

```
string = '1.1 2 -4259.8774  0.000000  0.707664  0.002210 -0.004314-0.004912-0.000823'
```

I tried with:

```
match = re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d+m?', string)
```

but I got:

```
['1.1', '-4259.8774', '0.000000', '0.707664', '0.002210', '-0.004314', '-0.004912',
 '-0.000823']
```

The second string '2' is missing. What I want is:

```
['1.1', '2',  '-4259.8774', '0.000000', '0.707664', '0.002210', '-0.004314', '-0.004912',
 '-0.000823']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `re.findall` here:

```py
string = '1.1 2 -4259.8774  0.000000  0.707664  0.002210 -0.004314-0.004912-0.000823'
nums = re.findall(r'(?:\b|-)\d+(?:\.\d+)?', string)
print(nums)
```

This prints:

```
['1.1', '2', '-4259.8774', '0.000000', '0.707664', '0.002210', '-0.004314', '-0.004912',
 '-0.000823']
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```regex
(?:\b|-)       match either a word boundary OR a minus sign, which is followed by
\d+(?:\.\d+)?  a whole number with optional decimal component
```

The idea here is that the left boundary of each number is either a `\b` word boundary, or the number starts with a minus sign.

Comment: This is a kind of perfect and professional solution this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Updated

Just do:

```
match = re.findall( r'-?\d+\.?\d*m?'  , string)
```

You accounted for missing the `.`, but not for anything following it. So with `\d*`, we fix it.

Comment: This won't work; check the input line again.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks! You're absolutely right. Updating now

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me you can check and let me know if something else that you need

```
import re
string='1.1 2 -4259.8774  0.000000  0.707664  0.002210 -0.004314-0.004912-0.000823'
match = re.findall( r'-?\d*\.?\d+m?'  , string)#After first \d i replace "+" with "*"
```

Output

```
['1.1',
 '2',
 '-4259.8774',
 '0.000000',
 '0.707664',
 '0.002210',
 '-0.004314',
 '-0.004912',
 '-0.000823']
```

Comment: This does not produce the right output either

Comment: While copying from my jupyter notebook i by mistake removed the plus from the previous expression

Comment: your output was wrong too lol. It's fixed now

Comment: yeah i know i reran to test it ...primarily i checked with the ouput he wanted it was same ...so before posting here i re ran it

Answer (score 0):

You can simply combine two regex patterns to filter out the desired numbers as below:

```
import re

>>> string='1.1 2 -4259.8774  0.000000  0.707664  0.002210 -0.004314-0.004912-0.000823'
>>> re.findall('-?\d+.?\d+|\d+', string)
>>> ['1.1', '2', '-4259.8774', '0.000000', '0.707664', '0.002210', '-0.004314', '-0.004912', '-0.000823']
```

In the first pattern `-?\d+.?\d+` the

`-?\d+.?` - Fetches any integer whether or not a negative fraction exists. For instance, it matches `-0.`

`\d+` - Fetches the digit after the decimal

In the second pattern

`\d+` - Fetches any whole numbers. For example, `2`, `3`, `15` etc.